# Can I use jQuery Ajax in Laravel + vue App?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, vue.js, http

I am Going to Develop Software as Service Web App and I am Confused about which way is better. I have experience of more than 3 years of working with PHP(core) and jQuery Ajax and now I am moving to Laravel and Vue js. so can i use jQuery Ajax for server interaction?? Yes I have read about axios and fetch and many other http ajax libraries and yes i know these are lighter than jQuery in terms of size and speed but still is it Good if i am using jQuery Ajax and Libraries in Vue Components?? And My Real Concern is can i face any issue which may caused by using jQuery ajax other than speed or size of library file Any Guide would be Appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Should you? Most developers choose not to. You don't need jQuery with Vue. Vue is just as simple, if not simpler, once you understand the component lifecycle. And it's way more powerful. Besides, it really doesn't have a steep learning curve, especially if you have some JavaScript experience. In the end jQuery and Vue do the same thing: they control DOM elements. But Vue does it more methodical and gives you easy to understand methods to interact with the process. Last, but not least, it's more efficient/performant.

Comment: No, there is no good reason to do this.  At best it unnecessarily increases the bundle size, since you're including two redundant libraries.  At worst you'll run into bugs when both frameworks try to control the DOM in conflicting ways.

Comment: The only scenario where it does make sense to load jQuery into Vue is when you have some third-party complex utility depending on jQuery which doesn't have a Vue version. In all fairness, Vue doesn't care what it renders and can be taught not to poke its nose into parts marked as "foreign". Vue can render Angular, React or even other Vue apps and, obviously, any jQuery controlled DOM. But just because it can be done doesn't mean it's the best option.

Comment: What if i use jQuery only for ajax and for using libraries like Datatables, DatePicker

Comment: Because My Main Concern is What is Consequences of this?

Comment: It's okay to use jquery for Ajax requests ONLY. But you have other options for that, like the native fetch method and the axios library.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, our team is using jquery together in vue.
But I regret this.
Because of this, you have to import jquery every time you render the screen.
And sometimes the rendering speed isn't right, so we used settimeout.

Comment: What if i use jQuery only for ajax and for using libraries like Datatables, DatePicker ??

Comment: Exactly, I also used it on the datepicker.
If possible, it's a good idea to find and use the package in npm the first time you create it.